# Temporarily change printer page size then revert back in Access 2007 using VBS

Tags: ms-access, printing, vbscript

I'm working on updating an Access front end.  Most of the time users are printing labels which are on a custom printer with page size set to 4"x6".  A new report needs to be printed regularly on Letter 8.5x11.

This also comes out of a normal printer, I've already added capability that let's users quickly change the current printer just before printing the report and it sets it back to the default.  However I'm still trying to figure out how I can save the current page size, change it to letter, then revert back to the label printing size, all in the VBS behind the form.

I saw [Printer Page Size Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236754/printer-page-size-problem)

But that doesn't seem to help.  I'll try the steps given there, but I'm also confused as to exactly what units the width and height values are in (what scale).  Are those dots and I have to simply to DPI math to figure out the height and width to set for each printing size?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the measurements are given in Twips

1440 Twips = 1 inch

A search shows this page has the info about changing printers and properties
http://access.mvps.org/access/reports/rpt0009.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a report from inside of access these links may contain what you are looking for:

http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=184762

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1267819